# Integrate Dojo Widgets inside React js application

Tags: javascript, reactjs, dojo

I am trying to Integrate Dojo Widgets inside React application. SO need to check if its possible and if yes , How its possible.

Answer (score 0):

Even if you succeed the code would be messy and really difficult to maintain. I suggest using WebComponents to isolate the code.

See: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Web_Components for a tutorial.